# How does a descriptor with __set__ but without __get__ work?

Tags: python, python-descriptors

I read somewhere about the fact you can have a descriptor with `__set__` and without `__get__`.

How does it work?

Does it count as a data descriptor? Is it a non-data descriptor?

Here is a code example:

```
class Desc:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __set__(self, inst, value):
        inst.__dict__[self.name] = value
        print("set", self.name)

class Test:
    attr = Desc("attr")

>>>myinst = Test()
>>> myinst.attr = 1234
set attr
>>> myinst.attr
1234
>>> myinst.attr = 5678
set attr
>>> myinst.attr
5678
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The descriptor you've given in the example is a data descriptor.

Upon setting the attribute, as any other data descriptor, it takes the highest priority and is called like so:

```
type(myinst).__dict__["attr"].__set__(myinst, 1234)
```

This in turn, adds `attr` to the instance dictionary according to your `__set__` method.

Upon attribute access, the descriptor is checked for having the `__get__` method but fails, causing for the search to be redirected to the instance's dictionary like so:

```
myinst.__dict__["attr"]
```

If it is not found in the instance dictionary, the descriptor itself is returned.

This behavior is shortly documented in the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors) like so:

> If it does not define `__get__()`, then accessing the attribute will
>   return the descriptor object itself unless there is a value in the
>   object’s instance dictionary.

Common usecases include avoiding `{instance: value}` dictionaries inside the descriptors, and caching values in an efficient way.

---

In Python 3.6, `__set_name__` was added to the descriptor protocol thus eliminating the need for specifying the name inside the descriptor. This way, your descriptor can be written like so:

```
class Desc:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name
    def __set__(self, inst, value):
        inst.__dict__[self.name] = value
        print("set", self.name)

class Test:
    attr = Desc()
```

Comment: Regarding the behaviour documented in the data model, there's a more thorough description in Raymond's [how to](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) guide.

Comment: @wim Actually, the reason I've raised this question at first is because it's not documented there. Nothing accounts for a data descriptor without `__get__`. Took me a while to figure out how it works. I'll add it to the pydocs myself I guess.